# Spinner gives Resource ID is not valid

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I used spinner sp  which filled with SpinnerAdapter adapter and when run the app the spinner will be filled with the first item of Arraylist list witch contains img and text but when I click on the spinner the app stop and Android Monitor says that : Resource ID #0x7f0e00d5 type #0x12 is not valid
. I watched some cases similar to my case but didn't help and here is my code :

```
   public class Serivce_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.service_activity);

        ArrayList<ItemData> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ItemData("tvsupport", R.drawable.com1_tvsupport));
        list.add(new ItemData("refrigerator", R.drawable.com2_refrigerator));
        list.add(new ItemData("wifi", R.drawable.com4_wifi));
        list.add(new ItemData("plumbing", R.drawable.com5_plumbing));

        Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.request_spinner1);
        SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, list);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

This is SpinnerAdapter class :

```
class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemData>{
    private int groupid;
    Activity context;
    private ArrayList<ItemData> list;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    SpinnerAdapter(Activity context, int groupid, int id, ArrayList<ItemData> list){
        super(context,id,list);
        this.list=list;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.groupid=groupid;
    }
    @NonNull
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
        View itemView=inflater.inflate(groupid,parent,false);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        imageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImageId());
        TextView textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        textView.setText(list.get(position).getText());
        return itemView;
    }
   public View getDropDowenView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    return getView(position,convertView,parent);
   }
}
```

ItemData :

```
public class ItemData {
    String text;
    Integer imageId;

    public ItemData(String text, Integer imageId) {
        this.text = text;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    public Integer getImageId(){
        return imageId;
    }
}
```

Spinner code :

```
                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/request_spinner1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                   >
                </Spinner>
```

spinner_layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/com0_yourrequest" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/selection"
        android:textColor="#2d5d13"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: clean your project and rebuild

Comment: I did but nothing change

Comment: minimize your `R.layout.spinner_layout` layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your spinner layout try removing this line

```
android:src="@drawable/com0_yourrequest"
```

I think this resource is missing. And check for other resources too if they are in your res folder or not also check names carefully.Hope it helps !

Check spellings here:

```
public View getDropDowenView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){ return getView(position,convertView,parent); }
```

and change spellings of getDropDowenView to getDropDownView

Comment: I removed the line and check all resources names but nothing changed

Comment: Ok bro I will look again your code deeply hope to catch your bug and kill that :)

Comment: SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, list); from this line remove R.id.text and write  SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, list); also update constructor for adapter too

Comment: public View getDropDowenView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    return getView(position,convertView,parent);
   } ....  here spelling of dropDOwn are incorrect try changing these first

Comment: I think that spelling issue is the main cause give it a try